# How to determine list-like objects in R, even when empty?

Tags: r

I have different possible input values, and I want to split them in two sets, one that contains single / atomar items, and one that contains multiple items or list-like structures that are empty.

For example, take these values:

```
123
"foo"
c()
c(c())
list()
list(list())
c(1, 2, 3)
c("a", "b", "c")
c(c("a", 1), "b", "c")
list("foo", "bar", c("baz", "blah"))
```

The first two should go into category A, the rest should go into category B.

I have tried various combinations of `is.recursive` or `is.atomic`, but I never get a correct split, as for example both `123` and `c(1)` are considered as atomic, numeric, and a vector of length 1.

I created an overview table of the different logical tests, but I can't seem to find something that distinguishes the first two lines from the others:

[image]

Am I missing something obvious here, like some property that'd help me distinguish those classes better?

### code to reproduce the table:

(except categories)

```
types <- list(123, "foo", c(), c(c()), list(), list(list()), c(1, 2, 3), c("a", "b", "c"), c(c("a", 1), "b", "c"), list("foo", "bar", c("baz", "blah")))

data.frame(types = paste(types), 
           is.recursive = sapply(types, is.recursive), 
           is.atomic = sapply(types, is.atomic), 
           is.character = sapply(types, is.character), 
           is.numeric = sapply(types, is.numeric), 
           is.vector = sapply(types, is.vector), 
           is.list = sapply(types, is.list), 
           length = sapply(types, length))
```

Comment: wouldn't `c(1)` also be category A?

Comment: Hm, I didn't realize that `c(1)` exactly the same as `1` (R internals are weird). If so, then that'd be category A as well, yes.

Comment: Ok, then the answer would be a combination of `length()`, `is.vector()` and `is.null()` (since `is.null(c())` returns a `TRUE`)

Comment: And yes, by design in R even integers of length 1 are vectors.

Comment: I think it's an interesting Question. However, you sould have a look of the correct object-terminology in R, since it differs to other languages. Perhaps for future visitors, the Q is more helpful then. You could start [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html).

Comment: Thanks for your pointers. I wrote an answer, but feel free to post your own, or a better solution – I'll happily accept it.

Comment: Added it with an additional link to `rapportools::is.empty`. Could also be used for parts of your problem.

Comment: Maybe just `is.atomic(NULL) & length(NULL) == 1` to catch category A, but not sure about your criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `length()`, `is.vector()` and `is.null()`

```
types <- list(123, "foo", c(), c(c()), list(), list(list()), c(1), c(1, 2, 3), c("a", "b", "c"), c(c("a", 1), "b", "c"), list("foo", "bar", c("baz", "blah")))
data.frame(types = paste(types), 
           is.recursive = sapply(types, is.recursive), 
           is.atomic = sapply(types, is.atomic), 
           is.character = sapply(types, is.character), 
           is.numeric = sapply(types, is.numeric), 
           is.vector = sapply(types, is.vector), 
           is.list = sapply(types, is.list), 
           length = sapply(types, length), 
           is.null = sapply(types, is.null), 
           typeof = sapply(types, typeof), 
           class = sapply(types, class), 

           # and now let's get to the mystery using 4 of these values:
           category = sapply(types, function(x){
             ifelse(is.null(x) || is.list(x) || (is.vector(x) && length(x) > 1), "B", "A")
           })) 
#                                  types ... category
#1                                   123 ...        A
#2                                   foo ...        A
#3                                   c() ...        B
#4                                c(c()) ...        B
#5                                list() ...        B
#6                          list(list()) ...        B
#7                                  c(1) ...        A
#8                            c(1, 2, 3) ...        B
#9                      c("a", "b", "c") ...        B
#10                c("a", "1", "b", "c") ...        B
#11 list("foo", "bar", c("baz", "blah")) ...        B
```

Furthermore, you should have a look at [`rapportools::is.empty()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rapportools/versions/1.0/topics/is.empty). However, it fails for nested lists (`list(list())`).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the hint from @loki I found a solution that works for me:

```
if (is.null(x) || is.list(x) || (is.vector(x) && (length(x) > 1))) {
    print("Category B")
} else {
    print("Category A")
}
```

This now produces:

```
0                                     # => "Option A"
123                                   # => "Option A"
"foo"                                 # => "Option A"
c(1)                                  # => "Option A"
c()                                   # => "Option B"
c(c())                                # => "Option B"
list()                                # => "Option B"
list(list())                          # => "Option B"
c(1, 2, 3)                            # => "Option B"
c("a", "b", "c")                      # => "Option B"
c(c("a", 1), "b", "c")                # => "Option B"
list("foo", "bar", c("baz", "blah"))  # => "Option B"
```

It is worth noting that `c(1) == 1`, and reading the [introduction to data structures](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html) helps, too.